# Where is the code that runs when a button is clicked in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, button

I'm trying to learn basic aspects of ASP.NET by analyzing the default Web Site project with Visual Studio 2010.

In the Register.aspx page there are fields for user registration and this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext"
    Text="Create User" ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
```

The button does register an user, but I can't find the piece of code that is run and even less how code was associated to that button. I've tried searching the solution for all the identifier keywords and found nothing relevant. Searching on the web mentions a Button.OnClick method that I also can't find.

Any info on the basic aspects of ASP.NET will help me; thanks in advance.

**Edit:** hierarchically, the button is inside:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="RegisterUserWizardStep" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="accountInfo">
                        <p class="submitButton">
```

There is a RegisterUser_CreatedUser method on the code behind and it does:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

    string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(continueUrl))
    {
        continueUrl = "~/";
    }
    Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
}
```

I was expecting some kind of inserting of user data on a database. I wonder, is this all that the button does?

Comment: What is this button in? Something like a gridview? It will probably have an OnCommand="SomeMethodName" property

Comment: There wasn't a OnCommand property, but it had a reference to a method on the code behind. I edited the question with more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you are looking it should be in `CreateUserWizardStep` control. I don't know much about this control but probably control looks for a child button having `CommandName = "MoveNext"`, then it hooks for its click event.

Try changing the `CommandName` to something else like "test", it should NOT hit the breakpoint on `RegisterUser_CreatedUser` event.

Also note that `CreatedUser` <- event is telling that user is created, now the rest of the code is just authenticating the same user. Behind that, the user is already been created and saved in database.

If you also look in the web.config you will find this ConnectionString

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Since you are using the Visual Studio's Default Web Application project, these all things are already done by Visual Studio for you.

Comment: Everything makes more sense now, thanks. About the `CreateUserWizardStep` I tested and yes it seems it looks for a `MoveNext` command.

Answer (score 0):

An aspx page will also have a "code behind" file with the same name but a different extension (the letters after the dot) which depends on the language it's written in. Visual basic files have a .vb extension while C# files have a .cs extension.

Try looking for Register.vb or Register.cs and see if that's more fruitful.

If you're using a development environment like Visual Studio, you'll probably find that in the Solution Explorer you can click to expand the aspx file and see its code behind file underneath. If you're not, you might want to pick up a copy of the free express edition:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs

When you find the code-behind, look for method called "MoveNext" - that's the code that'll run when you click the button, as specified by the CommandName attribute of the asp: Tag.

Comment: Thanks, I did that of searching for a `MoveNext` method but found nothing. I did find in the code behind however 2 methods, `PageLoad` and `RegisterUser_CreatedUser`. The latter was hit when I put a breakpoint and clicked the button, but I was expecting code like inserting the user data on a database, however I found, summarizing: `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...)` and `Response.Redirect(continueUrl)`. It is still confusing for me, I will dig in more.

Answer (score 0):

You've complicated a couple of things and you are completely not at fault but partly the project templates which comes with VS 2010 IDE. Let me try to help you one by one:

1. **Learning basics of ASP.Net** : For this you should be using "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" project template present in Visual Studio 2010. You've started with "ASP.NET Web Application" project template which has complicated things for
   you. To start afresh "ASP.NET Web Application" looks the obvious choice for anyone though but it comes with a precooked boiler-plate code meant for ASP.NET membership forms authentication and its associated controls which is the root cause of all your confusion. To get started with the basics take the "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" project template I've suggested above and then add a new "Web Form" and then add various basic server web controls like button or text box to get started with concepts like event handling and code behind stuff.
2. **Your other problem** -

   > "The button does register an user, but I can't find the piece of code
   >   that is run and even less how code was associated to that button"

   That is because the button that you are seeing on `Register.aspx` page is
   NOT an individual server web control but it is part of a composite control `asp:CreateUserWizard` instead. All the events of various controls be it a button, label or text box which are part of the `asp:CreateUserWizard` composite control is handled by the parent composite control `asp:CreateUserWizard`. You will NOT find all that code in your code behind file as this is present in `System.Web.dll` which is referenced in  your project.

   Since all the control events present on the composite control are handled by a common function written inside the code of composite control it has to distinguish exactly which control was clicked by the user (to take an appropriate action) which caused the current page post back for which `CommandName` property comes into picture. There is a switch case statement inside that common function for parent composite control which uses the `CommandName` property.

So essentially what happened is when you tried to start understanding basics of ASP.Net server web controls and event handling you actually got into the path of understanding ASP.Net Membership & role web server controls & providers which might be comparatively tough to understand and grasp initially. Hope this helps you to get started and further your understanding on ASP.Net world.